# Convert PriorityQueue to Map using Streams

Tags: java, java-stream, declarative

I have a Priority Queue of Integer: `PriorityQueue<Integer> pq`

I want to convert this to a map with this process in a declarative way:

1. `poll` should give the key
2. `size` should give the val

Here's what I've tried

```
pq.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(queue::poll, queue::size));
```

But this doesn't work because the method references aren't functional interfaces / Collectors.

So I'm looking for a way to make this happen.

I know I could just use a loop and put the entries into the map, but I'm looking to use a declarative style here.

Comment: So, ideally, the keys will be the elements in the queue, and the values will be the decreasing size of the queue as each key is polled?

Comment: Bluntly, a priority queue is not a good match for a declarative style.  The declarative style is designed for things that, at minimum, aren't being modified at the time.

Comment: @JacobG. That is correct. If the values in the heap(it's a max heap btw) in order are [8,4,2,2,1] then the map will end up like this {8:4, 4:3, 2:1, 1:0}

Comment: Why not use a `TreeMap` rather than a `PriorityQueue`?

Comment: I have an array of numbers. I then want to map each value in the array to an integer that is the number of values LESS THAN the current value in the array. So I won't know what value something needs to map to until after it's sorted (sort happens during insertion in a `TreeMap`). A `TreeSet` won't work because it doesn't allow duplicates (I need to allow duplicates)

Answer (score 2):

> I have an array of numbers. I then want to map each value in the array to an integer that is the number of values LESS THAN the current value in the array.

This is what you should have stated in your question :)

---

Because you want to do this functionally, I recommend solving it in two steps:

1. Build a frequency map from the initial array of integers
2. Use the frequency map to build your result map

The following snippet accomplishes this:

```
int[] array = { 42, 3, 100, 56, 3, 11 };

NavigableMap<Integer, Long> frequencyMap = Arrays.stream(array).boxed()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), TreeMap::new,
        Collectors.counting()));

Map<Integer, Long> countMap = frequencyMap.entrySet().stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey,
        entry -> frequencyMap.headMap(entry.getKey())
            .values().stream().mapToLong(Long::longValue).sum()));

System.out.println(countMap);
```

Output:

```
{3=0, 100=5, 56=4, 42=3, 11=2}
```

---

If you have a `PriorityQueue<Integer>` instead of an `int[]`, you can change:

```
Arrays.stream(array).boxed()
```

to:

```
queue.stream()
```

---

Regardless of the above snippet, I recommend solving this imperatively rather than functionally; it would be more readable, and you would be able to optimize it further.

Answer (score 2):

Your requirement stated in the comments made the requirement easier to understand.  *I have an array of numbers. I then want to map each value in the array to an integer that is the number of values LESS THAN the current value in the array*.

I really don't believe this operation easily lends itself to stream processing but you can do it in two steps.

- First, sort the array and store it in a `List`

```
int[] arr = {1,10,2,4,5,10,19,19,10};
List<Integer> list = Arrays.stream(arr).sorted().boxed().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

- Now simply collect them in a map using the index function of the `List` interface to get the relative number of items less than the current item.
- to accommodate duplicate keys I made the `value` field a List to store duplicate keys.  Indices of duplicate keys are considered to be equal
- I also specified a `LinkedHashMap` to preserve the sorted order of the keys

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> map = list
              .stream()
              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(a->a, 
                         LinkedHashMap::new,
                         Collectors.mapping(b->list.indexOf(b),
                               Collectors.toList())));

map.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);
```

Prints

```
1=[0]
2=[1]
4=[2]
5=[3]
10=[4, 4, 4]
19=[7, 7]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the `PriorityQueue` is collected to a map where the key is the int from the queue itself and the value is the amount of numbers smaller than it:

```
 int[] array = { 42, 2, 100, 100, 17, 2, 33 };
 List<Integer> ints = Arrays.stream(array).boxed().collect(toList());
 PriorityQueue<Integer> priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<Integer>(ints);


 TreeMap<Integer, Long> collect1 = priorityQueue.stream()
       .collect(toMap(
               Function.identity(),
               val -> priorityQueue.stream().filter(i -> val > i).count(),
               (l, r) -> l,
               TreeMap::new
               )
       );
```

output:

```
{2=0, 17=2, 33=3, 42=4, 100=5}
```

Answer (score 0):

To directly answer the question as I stated it, a PriorityQueue can be converted into a Map using streams like so:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> map = pq.stream().collect(ConcurrentHashMap::new, (integerIntegerHashMap, integer) -> integerIntegerHashMap.put(pq.poll(), pq.size()), ConcurrentHashMap::putAll);
```

This is a concurrent example, but replacing with HashMap (or any other non-concurrent Map) will work in those scenarios that don't require concurrency.

The `collect` method needs 3 arguments (docs: [Stream.collect](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BiConsumer-)):

1. This should be a supplier of the container (in this case, it's a constructor reference for a ConcurrentHashMap)
2. This should be an accumulator. It will take the container and an item and perform some operation (here I'm not using the item because I'm creating the mapping based solely on the state of the Priority Queue).
3. This should be a combiner. It will take 2 containers (like argument 1) and combine them.

The container here is a `ConcurrentHashMap`, and the combiner is the `putAll` method (because it takes a collection).

---

Now to provide the answer for the actual problem I was facing:
Having an array of integers, I needed to create a new array of integers that was a mapping of the original number to the number of values less than it in the input.

Input [1,2,3] -> Output [0, 1, 2]
Input [8,4,4] -> Output [2, 0, 0]

Here's how I followed the usage above:

```
int[] nums = ... (this is the input)
PriorityBlockingQueue<Integer> pq = Arrays.stream(nums).parallel().boxed().collect(()->new PriorityBlockingQueue<>(nums.length, Comparator.reverseOrder()), PriorityBlockingQueue::add, PriorityBlockingQueue::addAll);
Map<Integer, Integer> map = pq.stream().collect(ConcurrentHashMap::new, (integerIntegerHashMap, integer) -> integerIntegerHashMap.put(pq.poll(), pq.size()), ConcurrentHashMap::putAll);
int[] out = Arrays.stream(nums).mapToObj(operand -> map.get(operand)).mapToInt(Integer::intValue).toArray();
```

I set the container to be a Concurrent Max Heap (A concurrent priority queue with a reversed comparator).

Then pull the numbers out 1 by 1, giving them the appropriate mapping based on the pq. I don't think this second step can be done in parallel because 2 `poll` calls may finish consecutively, but we need to guarantee that `size` is called directly after each `poll`.

Lastly, iterate over the input elements and get the associated value from the map, and then convert into the result array.